# C# web api, how to handle exceptions and return appropriate status code

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core, webapi

I am creating a .net core web api that may throw an exception, in this case it cant find a person by id. If the person is not found I thrown an custom exception e.g. NotFoundException.

Is there a common/global place that I can intercept this exception and then return a 404 status code. 
Instead of writing custom code in each controller to handle all the the different possible exceptions. I was thinking maybe just a ExceptionHelper class maybe, but was wondering if there was a better way. As ideally I want to handle all exceptions in one place and return different status codes based on the exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could handle this in the `Configure` method of your `Startup.cs`. Something like the following:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler(appBuilder =>
    {
        appBuilder.Run(async context =>
        {
            var exceptionHandlerFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            if (exceptionHandlerFeature != null)
            {
                var exception = exceptionHandlerFeature.Error;
                if(exception == YourNotFoundException)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Could not find resource");
                }
                //you can also have global logging here eg:
                //var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Global exception logger");
                //logger.LogError(500, exception, exception.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("an unexpected fault happened. Try again later.");
            }

        });
    });
    ...
}
```

In your controllers then you raise your exceptions

Comment: Ok so tried this and can see the UseExceptionHandler being registered when I start up the web app but when I throw an exception from my business layer it is not going into this code and instead just returns a 500 status code

Comment: are you registering the middleware at the the beginning of your Configure method? and is the status code generic or the one you set inside the exceptionHandler?

Comment: Ahh thanks yes the code has this defined above which seemed to stop it working app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() so remove that and its works, Many thanks

Comment: I would normally handle that by `if (env.IsDevelopment())

            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else{ //the code snippet in my answer}`.